# wget force retry until there is a connection

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I have a bash script that uses `wget` running on a 3g device. I want the script to pause until I get a response so I have setup my code like this:

```
wget -t 0 -T 15 --retry-connrefused www.example.com
```

The problem is that when there is no connection at all (3g drops for a few seconds) the DNS can't resolve the host and `wget` stops retrying.

Is there a way to force retry until the connection comes back? I know I can write a loop but I want to know if there is a setting in `wget` I can use. If there is not what the best variable to build the loop on?

**More details:**

With the code I wrote, `wget` will retry but if the device has no Internet connection at all (for example I pull out the 3g dongle from the device) it will stop retrying telling me it can't resolve the host address. It sends that after the 15 seconds defined by `-T 15`

```
wget: unable to resolve host address
```

Comment: Wget does retry with most network problems. I think we need more details.

Comment: Why not calling wget in a simple loop?

Comment: Yes but I was wondering if there is a setting that has been tested by people rather than writing my own loop.

Comment: If you're planning on *not* using a loop, you probably don't need the `bash` tag.  
Also, as far as "does `wget` have an option", that's what the man pages are for!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This loop should do this:

```
while true;do
wget -T 15 -c http://example.com && break
done
```

---

**How it works:**

1. In case there is no network connection, the `while loop` will not break and it will run the `wget` command continuously and keep printing error message.
2. As soon as it gets connected to the Internet, `wget` starts resolving the host and getting the files.
3. Now if the connection is lost or some other error occurs, default retry (don't use `0` or `inf` i.e unlimited retry, use limited value) of `wget` will retry to get the files until timeout of 15 seconds reached. After 15 seconds the `wget` command will fail and print error output and thus the `while loop` won't break. So it will again reach in a state where there is no connection or such and keep printing error message.
4. Again as soon as it gets connected or the error is resolved, `wget` starts resolving the host and getting the files. These steps (1-4) continue as long as the files are not downloaded completely.
5. This `wget` command uses `-c` option, i.e resume option. So every instances of `wget` will start (downloading) from where it left off.
6. When the files get downloaded completely and the `wget` command succeeds, the loop will break.

Comment: Question on step 3: how come the while loop does not break? Why doesn't the next step `&& break` get executed?

Comment: @alex `break` will only execute if the `wget` command finishes without error because of `&&`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that you can use to resolve your problem

```
FILENAME=$1
DOWNURL=$2

wget -O "`echo $FILENAME`" "`echo $DOWNURL`"
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")

while [ $FILESIZE \< 1000 ]; do
    sleep 3
    wget -O "`echo $FILENAME`" "`echo $DOWNURL`"
    FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
done
```

The script forces the download to continue until it finishes. The `1000` could be changed to fit whatever size file you are downloading.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a loop. You could end up with multiple downloads. Rather invent smarter way to check the network connection. Try pinging some sites beforehand and issue wget only if they succeed. If they fail the script could wait and try the test again. Ping can do quiet tests and use counts and deadlines for returns.

Comment: so if it keeps dropping the connection the download will never finish and you are stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @jgr208 One would have a limit on the number of tests, but Mika did want wget to keep waiting.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of wget supports it, you should use `--retry-on-host-error` to retry name resolution failures.

From the man page for wget:

> ‘--retry-on-host-error’
>
> Consider host errors, such as “Temporary failure in name resolution”, as non-fatal, transient errors.

source: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html